# Create a dictionary that uses the same pairs from another dictionary, but keys are translated

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dictionary "aaComp" that has the same keys and values as another dictionary "codonComp", then translate the keys of aaComp using another dictionary "rnaCodonTable".  I need the same pairings of values and keys, but the keys need to be under a different name.  I attempted to write this myself, but ended up with two identical dictionaries:

```
aaComp = {key.translate(self.rnaCodonTable):value for key, value in codonComp.items()}
```

The two original dictionaries are as follows:

```
rnaCodonTable = {
# RNA codon table
# U
'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C',  # UxU
'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C',  # UxC
'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': 'STOP', 'UGA': 'STOP',  # UxA
'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': 'STOP', 'UGG': 'W',  # UxG
# C
'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R',  # CxU
'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R',  # CxC
'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R',  # CxA
'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R',  # CxG
# A
'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S',  # AxU
'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S',  # AxC
'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R',  # AxA
'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R',  # AxG
# G
'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G',  # GxU
'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G',  # GxC
'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G',  # GxA
'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G'   # GxG
}
codonComp = {'UUU': 0, 'UCU': 0, 'UAU': 0, 'UGU': 0, 'UUC': 2, 'UCC': 0, 'UAC': 2, 'UGC': 1, 'UUA': 1, 'UCA': 0, 'UAA': 1, 'UGA': 0, 'UUG': 0, 'UCG': 0, 'UAG': 0, 'UGG': 2, 'CUU': 1, 'CCU': 0, 'CAU': 0, 'CGU': 0, 'CUC': 0, 'CCC': 2, 'CAC': 0, 'CGC': 1, 'CUA': 1, 'CCA': 0, 'CAA': 2, 'CGA': 1, 'CUG': 4, 'CCG': 1, 'CAG': 6, 'CGG': 1, 'AUU': 0, 'ACU': 0, 'AAU': 0, 'AGU': 0, 'AUC': 2, 'ACC': 0, 'AAC': 2, 'AGC': 1, 'AUA': 2, 'ACA': 1, 'AAA': 2, 'AGA': 0, 'AUG': 5, 'ACG': 0, 'AAG': 2, 'AGG': 3, 'GUU': 0, 'GCU': 0, 'GAU': 0, 'GGU': 0, 'GUC': 2, 'GCC': 4, 'GAC': 5, 'GGC': 2, 'GUA': 1, 'GCA': 1, 'GAA': 0, 'GGA': 0, 'GUG': 0, 'GCG': 4, 'GAG': 3, 'GGG': 0}
```

Can this be written on one line, or do I have to write it as two lines?  After seeing one comment, I realize what I'm asking for is more complicated than I thought.  Typing the full desired result would be difficult, but there are several keys in the rnaCodonTable that match to the letter F.  In codonComp, there is a total of 2 (0+2) codons (the 3 letter items) that match the keys in rnaCodonTable for F.  aaComp would show this as 'F':2 .

Comment: Thanks for posting some example data. It looks like you will get duplicate keys, so what would you want to happen in that case? Could you post the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because duplicates are possible, a `for` loop with `collections.defaultdict` is best:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rnaCodonTable = {'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C', 'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C', 'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': 'STOP', 'UGA': 'STOP', 'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': 'STOP', 'UGG': 'W', 'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R', 'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R', 'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R', 'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R', 'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S', 'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S', 'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R', 'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R', 'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G', 'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G', 'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G', 'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G'}
codonComp = {'UUU': 0, 'UCU': 0, 'UAU': 0, 'UGU': 0, 'UUC': 2, 'UCC': 0, 'UAC': 2, 'UGC': 1, 'UUA': 1, 'UCA': 0, 'UAA': 1, 'UGA': 0, 'UUG': 0, 'UCG': 0, 'UAG': 0, 'UGG': 2, 'CUU': 1, 'CCU': 0, 'CAU': 0, 'CGU': 0, 'CUC': 0, 'CCC': 2, 'CAC': 0, 'CGC': 1, 'CUA': 1, 'CCA': 0, 'CAA': 2, 'CGA': 1, 'CUG': 4, 'CCG': 1, 'CAG': 6, 'CGG': 1, 'AUU': 0, 'ACU': 0, 'AAU': 0, 'AGU': 0, 'AUC': 2, 'ACC': 0, 'AAC': 2, 'AGC': 1, 'AUA': 2, 'ACA': 1, 'AAA': 2, 'AGA': 0, 'AUG': 5, 'ACG': 0, 'AAG': 2, 'AGG': 3, 'GUU': 0, 'GCU': 0, 'GAU': 0, 'GGU': 0, 'GUC': 2, 'GCC': 4, 'GAC': 5, 'GGC': 2, 'GUA': 1, 'GCA': 1, 'GAA': 0, 'GGA': 0, 'GUG': 0, 'GCG': 4, 'GAG': 3, 'GGG': 0}

aaComp = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in codonComp.items():
    aaComp[rnaCodonTable[k]] += v
```

`aaComp` will be

```
{'F': 2, 'S': 1, 'Y': 2, 'C': 1, 'L': 7, 'STOP': 1, 'W': 2, 'P': 3, 'H': 0, 'R': 6, 'Q': 8, 'I': 4, 'T': 1, 'N': 2, 'K': 4, 'M': 5, 'V': 3, 'A': 9, 'D': 5, 'G': 2, 'E': 3}
```